# Tkinter - How to center a Widget (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I started with the GUI in Python and have a problem. 
I've added widgets to my frame, but they're always on the left side.
I have tried some examples from the internet, but I did not manage it .
I tried `.place`, but it does not work for me. Can one show me how to place the widgets in the middle?

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def site_open(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

window = tk.Tk()

window.title('Test')
window.geometry('500x300')

StartPage = tk.Frame(window)
FirstPage = tk.Frame(window)

for frame in (StartPage, FirstPage):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

lab = tk.Label(StartPage, text='Welcome to the Assistant').pack()
lab1 = tk.Label(StartPage, text='\n We show you helpful information about you').pack()
lab2 = tk.Label(StartPage, text='\n \n Name:').pack()
ent = tk.Entry(StartPage).pack()
but = tk.Button(StartPage, text='Press', command=lambda:site_open(FirstPage)).pack()

lab1 = tk.Label(FirstPage, text='1Page').pack()
but1 = tk.Button(FirstPage, text='Press', command=lambda:site_open(StartPage)).pack()

site_open(StartPage)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: which widgets do you want centered, and do you want them centered left-to-right or top-to-bottom, or both? Will there be other widgets? There's no single way to center widgets, since the placement of one widget can affect the placement of another.

Comment: I just want to center the first label, centered left to right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have created `window`, add:

```
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

More at [The Grid Geometry Manager](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different Layout Managers. I suggest you either use [The Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) **or** [The Pack Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm).

Once you have decided which one you would like to use, it is easier to help you :)

For example you could use the Grid Geometry Manager with two rows and two columns and place the widgets like so:

```
label1 = Label(start_page, text='Welcome to the Assistant')
# we place the label in the page as the fist element on the very left 
# and allow it to span over two columns
label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w', columnspan=2) 

button1 = Button(start_page, text='Button1', command=self.button_clicked)
button1.grid(row=1, column=0)

button2 = Button(start_page, text='Button2', command=self.button_clicked)
button2.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

This will lead to having the label in the first row and below the two buttons next to each other.